# Is it possible to do nested sort with a conditional query on a sort element

Tags: elasticsearch

we have following structure in an index - following is only a partial and doc relevant for this question.

```
"instance" : {
  "id" : 1,
  {"instFields": [
  {
    "sourceFieldId": 2684,
    "fieldValue": "false",
    "fieldBoolean": false
  },
  {
    "sourceFieldId": 1736,
    "fieldValue": "DODGE",
    "fieldString": "DODGE"
  },

  {
    "sourceFieldId": 1560,
    "fieldValue": "GRAY",
    "fieldString": "GRAY"
  },
  {
    "sourceFieldId": 1558,
    "fieldValue": "CHALLENGER",
    "fieldString": "CHALLENGER"
  },
  {
    "sourceFieldId": 1556,
    "fieldValue": "2010",
    "fieldDouble": 2010
  }

  ]
}
```

first user query is give me all `instance`s where `sourceFieldId=1736` - this returns all the `DODGE` `instances[]` - all this is working fine with an appripriate Elastic Search query. now when user is seeing all `DODGE` records - user wants to sort by any of those `sourceFieldIds` for e.g. say user is wanting to `sort` results by - color - `sourceFieldId=1560`.

say we have following `sort` query

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "filtered": {
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "instance.dataSourceId": "196"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "instance.dsTypeId": "5"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "nested": {
                          "query": {
                            "filtered": {
                              "query": {
                                "match_all": {}
                              },
                              "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "instance.instFields.sourceFieldId": "1558"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "instance.instFields.fieldString.raw": "challenger"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "path": "instance.instFields"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "path": "instance",
            "inner_hits": {
              "name": "inner_data"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "instance.entitlements.roleId": {
                            "query": "1",
                            "type": "boolean"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "instance.entitlements.read": {
                            "query": "true",
                            "type": "boolean"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "path": "instance.entitlements"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
},
"sort": {
"instance.instFields.fieldString.raw": {
  "order": "asc",
  "nested_path": "instance.instFields",
  "nested_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                      "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "filter": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "instance.dataSourceId": "196"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "instance.dsTypeId": "5"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "nested": {
                              "query": {
                                "filtered": {
                                  "query": {
                                    "match_all": {}
                                  },
                                  "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                      "must": [
                                        {
                                          "term": {
                                            "instance.instFields.sourceFieldId": "1558"
                                          }
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "term": {
                                            "instance.instFields.fieldString.raw": "challenger"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              "path": "instance.instFields"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path": "instance",
                "inner_hits": {
                  "name": "inner_data1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "instance.entitlements.roleId": {
                                "query": "1",
                                "type": "boolean"
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "instance.entitlements.read": {
                                "query": "true",
                                "type": "boolean"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path": "instance.entitlements"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
}
```

resulting docs must return entire `instance` with all the `soureceFields` - as on a user page it displays other values of `DODGE` as well.

now issue is- `sort` query still has to have knowledge to sort `where` - `"sourceFieldId": 1560` (which is a sourceFieldId for color) to `sort` on `color`

is there a way to achieve such a `sort` query in ES without using dynamic scripting/dynamic templating? something like

```
"sort": {
   "instance.instFields.fieldString.raw": (where sourceFieldId=1560?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to achieve this using [nested_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting) option in `sort`

From the documentation:

> nested_filter A filter that the inner objects inside the nested path
>   should match with in order for its field values to be taken into
>   account by sorting. Common case is to repeat the query / filter inside
>   the nested filter or query. By default no nested_filter is active.

For example to sort on color field it would be:

```
{
   "sort": {
      "instance.instFields.fieldValue.raws": {
         "order": "asc",
         "nested_path": "instance.instFields",
         "nested_filter": {
            "term": {
               "instance.instFields.sourceFieldId": "1560"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

*Edited*

```
"sort": [{
      "instance.instFields.fieldValue": {
         "order": "asc",
         "nested_path": "instance.instFields",
         "nested_filter": {
            "term": {
               "instance.instFields.sourceFieldId": "1560"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "instance.instFields.fieldValue": {
         "order": "asc",
         "nested_path": "instance.instFields",
         "nested_filter": {
            "term": {
               "instance.instFields.sourceFieldId": "1558"
            }
         }
      }
   }

   ]
```

Comment: i have updated my question. included entire `sort` query which already has `nested_filter` in it so that's not an issue. if you can take another look at the question. thanks.

Comment: Can you post the entire query not just the sort part

Comment: done- just updated question with an entire query. I am wanting to sort on `sourceFieldId` as explained in the question BUT where `sourceFieldId=1560`- any ideas?

Comment: is there any reason for the orginal query to be repeated in sort ? I have updated the answer to show how the result could be sorted by color. Also the actual query could be more simple. There is not reason for "match_all' in the nested query each time.

Comment: thanks. it's working. next challenge is getting `sort`ing working on multiple `nested_path`s e.g. say there is another `nested` level under `instance.instFields` - so there are two `nested_path`s and corresponding `nested_filter`s . do you if there is a way to address this use case?

Comment: I have edited the answer since [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) takes an array of  "sort criteria objects" you can  specify a sequence of sort criteria